# Python: DLL Load Failed after code was previously working

Tags: python, github, package, anaconda, installation

I have a custom Python package installed on my computer. I use Anaconda to manage Python packages and I use the Spyder IDE. I am running Python 3.5 on Windows 7. I installed this custom package about one month ago and have been using the code without any problems for the past month.

But, out of nowhere, I got a bunch of errors in Spyder and now when I try to import the custom package I get an error which says:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found
```

The package is still installed in my Anaconda site_packages directory. I also tried re-installing it from github using pip install and it installed with no errors.

The only thing that changed is that I installed the MKL Basemap package today. Could that somehow effect DLL files? If so why?

I have no idea what is going on but I am seriously pulling my hair about this one and about ready to yell profanities at my computer.

Any help is apprecaited.

Here is the full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-6e6bfa427774>", line 20, in <module>
    import bezpy

  File "C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bezpy\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import mt

  File "C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bezpy\mt\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .site import *

  File "C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bezpy\mt\site.py", line 12, in <module>
    import scipy.interpolate

  File "C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\__init__.py", line 160, in <module>
    from .interpolate import *

  File "C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py", line 16, in <module>
    import scipy.linalg

  File "C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\__init__.py", line 190, in <module>
    from ._decomp_update import *

  File "scipy/linalg/_decomp_update.pyx", line 1, in init scipy.linalg._decomp_update (scipy\linalg\_decomp_update.c:37717)

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the stack trace you'l see that it's `scipy` that's failing. The installation of the basemap package probably messed up the dlls. Try reinstalling scipy see if that helps.